# Merging 2 Dictionaries, with a {X: Y}, {Y: Z} Relationship

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I wish to combine 2 dictionaries for the purposes of data standardisation... The first dictionary contains the remote data headers, and what the headers should be transformed to...

```
Dict 1 = {
"timestamp": "TimeStamp", 
"name": "SiteName",
"energy": "PowerExport", 
}

Dict 2 = {
"TimeStamp": "13-02-2017 12:34:05", 
"PowerExport": 32, 
"SiteName": "Site 104",
}
```

The intention is to merge these 2 dictionaries so that it looks something like this:

```
Dict 1 = {
"timestamp": "13-02-2017 12:34:05", 
"name": "Site 104",
"energy": 32, 
}
```

So the intention is to convert {X: Y}, {Y: Z} in to {X: Z}.

Comment: Dependent on the context, there could be instances where Dict 2, doesn't include all of the data mapping stated by Dict 1 (However Dict 1, will always have all the required headers). In addition, I have no control over the order of Dict 2, so it might be that TimeStamp is in position 4 or equally in position 7.

Comment: Dicts don't have order anyway, so that second point doesn't apply.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clearing that up. Post updated to avoid confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a single dict comprehension:

```
new_dict = {k: dict_2.get(v) for k, v in dict_1.iteritems()}
```

This uses `get` to ensure that it does not fail if the key is not found in dict_2; the value will be None if that happens. Dicts have no order, so that is not something to worry about.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much for the swift reply! It really is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

another option, if you want a one liner that doesn't use any imports, is:

`{key:Dict2[value] for key,value in Dict1.items() if Dict2.has_key(value)}`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15196841)

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr doesn't it? it does the ` {X: Y}, {Y: Z} in to {X: Z}` part that op requested

Comment: code only answers aren't really desired anyway + how does it differ from the already accepted answer?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr better? (im still new on SO so im trying :) )

Answer (score 0):

Or without a dictionary comprehension:

```
dict1 = {
    "timestamp": "TimeStamp", 
    "name": "SiteName",
    "energy": "PowerExport"
}
dict2 = {
    "TimeStamp": "13-02-2017 12:34:05", 
    "PowerExport": 32, 
    "SiteName": "Site 104"
}

d = {}
for k in dict1:
    if dict1[k] in dict2:
        d[k] = dict2[dict1[k]]
```